# ng-bind-html with html + angularjs inside

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

In one of the pages of my app, I am using ng-bind-html to show some text through a function:

```
<ng-bind-html
  ng-bind-html="getText(textContainer)">
</ng-bind-html>
```

getText() returns some text which is html code + some angularjs, something like:

```
    <table> 
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td> 
        SOME TEXT
        <textarea data-ng-bind-html="getOtherText(index)" data-ng-keyup="updateOtherText(index)</textarea>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Now, I don't know if this is feasible (I am aware that it could be not particular good), but the second bind and the keyup don't seem to fire. Could someone explain me why please?